# Django Form Wizard For Dynamic Sized Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic, wizard

So I have a dynamic form which can have an arbitrary size from one field to 100 or more and I was wondering how it would be possible to use Django's form wizard for that dynamic form. The fields are generated in the __init__ of the form by adding them to the fields dictionary.

```
class MyDynamicForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    parent = kwargs.pop('parent')
    super(MyDynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
    # Add each element into self.fields
    for element in parent.elements:
        if element.type == TEXT_FIELD:
           self.fields[element.name] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
        elif element.type == CHECKBOX_FIELD:
            self.fields[element.name] = forms.BooleanField()
        elif element.type == SINGLE_CHOICE_FIELD:
            self.fields[element.name] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=element.choices.split(','))
        elif element.type = MULTIPLE_CHOICE_FIELD:
            self.fields[element.name] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=element.choices.split(','))
```

I assume that I could wrap this form class in a function and only have it return the form class which only creates a portion of the fields by doing `for element in parent.elements[start:end]` rather than what I'm doing to create each wizard class but I feel like this is not the correct approach. How should I go about this, is there a correct way? Or is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to show us your code if you want a critique of it.

Comment: Sorry about that sir, my code has been added!